# What is last digit (in a different radix)?

Tags: computer-science, information-theory, number-systems

What is last digit of $AD^{AD}$  (hexadecimal)  in octal?

How is it found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(2n+1)^2=8\,\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1\equiv1\quad\mod8,$ we have $x^y\equiv x\quad\mod8$ for odd $x,y.$ Since the last octal digit of hexadecimal AD is 5, that is your answer.

Comment: Can you add the missing steps?

Answer (score 1):

AD = 10*16 + 13 = 173.

173^173 mod 8 = (173 mod 8)^173 mod 8 = 5^173 mod 8

5^1 mod 8 = 5, 5^2 mod 8 = 1, 5^3 mod 8 = 5 etc., so 5^173 mod 8 = 5.

Comment: How take it without calculator?

Comment: That was without a calculator...